# Get the number of records from MDX query with Subcubes

Tags: count, mdx

I'm developing a system for generate `mdx` queries from entity "FilterCriterias" and related info like the number of records of a query, so I need a generic way to get the number of records of a `mdx` query than use subcubes. In a normal query I do something like:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [MyCount] AS 
    Count([Date].[Date].MEMBERS) 
SELECT 
  {[MyCount]} ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

But I have problems when use this way in queries a little more complexes like that

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [MyCount] AS 
    Count([Date].[Date].MEMBERS) 
SELECT 
  {[MyCount]} ON 0
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Sales Amount]} ON 0
   ,{[Date].[Date].&[20050701] : [Date].[Date].&[20051231]} ON 1
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {[Sales Channel].[Sales Channel].&[Internet]} ON 0
    FROM [Adventure Works]
  )
);
```

I guess the logic response could be the number of records of [Date].[Members] left in the subcube, but I get a result without columns and rows. I'm newbie in mdx language and I don't understand this behavior. Exists some generic way to get the number of records from a "base" query just like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM () in plain SQL?

Answer (score 1):

The structure is quite different to a ralational `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ()`.

I believe that the structure of a sub-select will be very similar to that of a sub-cube and reading through this definition from `MSDN` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144774.aspx) of what a sub-cube contains tells us that it isn't a straight filter like in a relational query:

[image]

Admittedly I still find this behaviour rather "enigmatic" (a polite way of saying "I do not understand it")

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Well, I still search a way for get a generic solution for this requirement but seems don't exists. I begin start search for a different behavior of ADOMD connection when call the ExecuteNonQuery and get the number of affected rows. Now a SELECT query always return 1 affected record. It's possible know the number of rows returneds for the query inside the server? The goal is the server response be only a number, not a possible BIG set of data very weight for receive.